# Omnigraffle text replacement object for low fidelity and responsive wireframes

Tags: omnigraffle

Replacing text with rectangles is a well established graphic technique for wireframes. However, I am having difficulty creating these quickly in Omnigraffle and none of my stencils have these text-replace elements.

¿Anyone know the solution?

The problem with simply creating them individually is design consistency (e.g., alignment, spacing, &c). A better technique would be similar to how tables are used: once the stencil is created, all you have to do to add another row of text would be to drag the shape until another rectangle appears.

[image: Wirify shows the technique]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the free font Blokk. Made especially for this situation. Have been using it myself and it works like a charm.

*Bonustip: Make sure you use a specific word or a specific letter combination though because if you run a spell check on your Omnigraffle document you have to skip through all the content.*

http://blokkfont.com/

Comment: There are many things I like about this solution and will definitely add it to my tool set. Nevertheless, it is not THE solution. Obviously, it is significantly cleaner than using a standard typeface. However, the spaces between words are a bit distracting and do not add any visual information. Even Wirify's example above leaves out the spaces and only uses the line length. THE solution should simply use a consistent line length, because even the jagged paragraph edge unnecessarily calls attention to itself. [Blokk Font](http://blokkfont.com/img/blokk_units.png)